# Script timeout in Spidermonkey

Tags: javascript, timeout, spidermonkey

How can I set a timeout on execution of a Javascript code in Spidermonkey?

The documentation says that JS_SetOperationCallback could resolve this problem, but how can I define the max interval time between calls to operation callback?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [that API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JS_SetOperationCallback) are slightly outdated, unfortunately -- updating them is now on my todo list. :-)

However, this API is fairly do-it-yourself: JS_TriggerOperationCallback can be called (thread-safely) from a thread of your own that waits for a pre-defined period of time. The browser does this with a watchdog thread scheme that causes the classic "slow script dialog" to appear on infinite loops.